# How to insert an image in excel work book sheet

Tags: visualforce

Hi there I have created excel workbook with help of XML Spreadsheet Reference.
I am unable to insert the image in the sheet.
can any one please suggest me how to insert an image in the sheet.
below is the code which i have used to generate sheet with multiple tabs.

```
<apex:page id="pg" standardStylesheets="false" controller="MorningReportwithExcelTabs" contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel#CAMorningReportWithMultipleTabs.xls" >

{!xmlheader}

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
        <WindowHeight>8535</WindowHeight>
        <WindowWidth>12345</WindowWidth>
        <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
        <WindowTopY>90</WindowTopY>
        <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
        <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
    </ExcelWorkbook>
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <Author></Author>
    <LastAuthor></LastAuthor>
    <Company></Company>
    <Version>11.6360</Version>
    </DocumentProperties>
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
        <Borders/>
        <Font ss:bgcolor="#FF0000"/>
        <Interior ss:bgcolor="#FF0000"/>
        <NumberFormat/>
        <Protection/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s16">
        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="1"/>
        <Interior ss:Color="#92D050" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="CenterAcrossSelection"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s23">
        <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="0" ss:bgcolor="#FF0000"/>

    </Style>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Top 5 Daily Orders">
 <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="200">


        <Column ss:Width="200"/>
        <Column ss:Width="200"/>
        <Column ss:Width="80"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Column ss:Width="100"/>


            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16" ><Data ss:Type="String">Rep Name</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16" ><Data ss:Type="String">Bill to </Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">State</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Ready</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Toolbox w/I-Ready</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">i-Ready</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Training</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Brigance</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"><Data ss:Type="String">Other</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">TOTAL</Data></Cell>

            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">OGDEN</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">ELK GROVE USD</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">CA</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">123456678901</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2343</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2344</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">23342</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2342432</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">55789</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="Number">23424543</Data></Cell>

            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">SHARZER</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">ELK GROVE USD</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">CA</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">3,220</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">4,210</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">5,320</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2,456,100</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">23,456,789</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">45675</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="Number">176100</Data></Cell>

            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">DOMESTIC HOUSE</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">ELK GROVE USD</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">CA</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">3,220</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">4,210</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">5,320</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2,456,100</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">23,456,789</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">67788</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="Number">176100</Data></Cell>

            </Row>

            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">MCMATH</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">ELK GROVE USD</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">CA</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">3,220</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">4,210</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">5,320</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">2,456,100</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">23,456,789</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="Number">87766</Data></Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="Number">176100</Data></Cell>

            </Row>
```

Comment: I'd do this with Conga Composer which will give you vastly more formatting flexibility in Excel - because you use Excel as the template and merge in SFDC values